# How future-proof is the arXiv license?

Tags: arxiv, open-access, politics, law, backup-archiving

The [arXiv license](https://arxiv.org/licenses/nonexclusive-distrib/1.0/license.html) is the "default" license under which most preprints are being submitted to the arXiv at least in my subject. Out of dark curiosity, I am wondering how safe it is at doing what it is meant to do, namely ensure that these preprints are widely and freely available through the reasonable future. Let me quote the license in full:

> The URI http://arxiv.org/licenses/nonexclusive-distrib/1.0/ is used to record the fact that the submitter granted the following license to arXiv.org on submission of an article:
>
> I grant arXiv.org a perpetual, non-exclusive license to distribute this article.
>
> I certify that I have the right to grant this license.
>
> I understand that submissions cannot be completely removed once accepted.
>
> I understand that arXiv.org reserves the right to reclassify or reject any submission.

I am wondering what this entails in any of the following hypothetical scenarios:

- Cornell University decides to sell arXiv.org off for whatever reasons (which may be far lesser reasons than bankruptcy -- e.g., someone might catch wind of the fact that a great many PDF files are not ADA-compliant; or publishers might unleash a barrage of lawsuits on Cornell for hosting what they believe are not quite preprints; or it is simply decided that continued hosting of the arXiv is too much of a cost center), and the new proprietors don't see public access as a priority. Someone with a [full dump](https://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data_s3) uploads it on a server in the Ukraine.
  (Comparable cases: [SSRN bought by Elsevier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Science_Research_Network), although the full-dump analogy is broken here -- I don't know if anyone ended up re-hosting the papers taken down.)
- The HTTP protocol and the WWW are superseded by something new and shiny, and the ".org" domain and the notion of a "server" lose their meaning; arXiv involves into a service which may have a hard time arguing that it is the same arXiv.org ("a highly-automated electronic archive and distribution server") that the license was granted to. (Comparable cases: The precursor of arXiv.org was a mailing list; it is far from obvious that mailing out a preprint on an ephemeral medium like a mailing list grants any rights for future perpetual hosting on the internet. Now imagine the next step after the mailing list and the internet, whatever that may be; ignore the current social media hype, which is not a relevant development for hosting documents.)
- Various countries block the official arXiv domains (or force arXiv to geo-fence them out), causing the creation of multiple not-quite-official mirrors, some even on the dark web (.onion) or otherwise hidden-from-view. How can these mirrors argue that the arXiv license was granted to them?
- The arXiv team splits along a political fault-line, resulting in two different groups/servers/teams with claims to the arXiv name. Are they both allowed to host the papers?
- The TeX and PDF formats lose their universal support, and new formats come up (or new versions, breaking backwards compatibility); the arXiv team can no longer keep up writing compatibility scripts, and volunteers end up fixing the papers and posting them on github. (The compatibility nightmare is already happening to some extent -- the arXiv has its share of [broken PDFs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9409090.pdf), and I recall even seeing a TeX that did not compile until I made a tweak. So far, most of the damage has been repaired, probably with a lot of manual drudgery, but the arXiv is getting more and more papers, and the next generation of formats to be deprecated will have a much higher amount of papers posted in it.)

What these scenarios all have in common is that, in a sense, the arXiv does not disappear -- it just evolves, changes its skin, reincarnates, as times change. My question is: Does the license follow it, or will the "new arXiv" be in troubles trying to prove that it still has a right to host preprints uploaded under the (standard) arXiv license back in the early 2000s?

Comment: PS: There is always the possibility that in 20 years, copyright will not apply to scientific work. But it is far from a certainty, whence this question.

Comment: arXiv.org is the entity, not the website itself. While Cornell hosts it, I do not know the legal standing of the entity itself. Cornell has a long history of hosting such sites (including the APS archives).

Comment: @JonCuster: according to the arXiv FAQ "CUL [Cornell University Library] holds the overall administrative and financial responsibility for arXiv's operation and development, with guidance from its Member Advisory Board (MAB) and its Scientific Advisory Board (SAB)". And on the homepage: "arXiv is owned and operated by Cornell University, a private not-for-profit educational institution." So it looks like arXiv.org is not a separate entity, but legally part of Cornell. I do not have any legal training, but I would assume that ultimately they have the possibility they sell or transfer ...

Comment: .. the rigths to arXiv.org and the content there to another party. That is, I would expect that the rights could be transferred to the new "legal successor" of arXiv, even if it would not be called arXiv.org any more. In the end this seems to be more of a legal question, and I don't think it would be specific to the arXiv, but also applies to journals, for example.

Comment: Note that the license transfer is non-exclusive. Should Cornell disappear, the authors would still hold their rights to the work to share with arXiv 2.0.

Comment: These concerns are an excellent argument for choosing one of the Creative Commons licenses for your arXiv submission. They are just better in every way.

Comment: @JonCuster Often not, since many authors have since signed their rights away to some commercial publisher, after having submitted to arXiv when they had the right to do so. Also the authors might be dead/forgetful.

Comment: @BorisBukh - well, that is an entirely separate question. Overall I'm having a hard time figuring out a credible scenario where Cornell dumps arXiv.

Comment: @JonCuster Many things were not credible before they happened. The point is not having to worry about this being one of them.

Comment: @BorisBukh - well, I'm not going to chisel my papers on to stone tablets and bury them in the desert... If your worst worry is arXiv disappearing forever, count yourself lucky.

Comment: Interesting speculative question, but I think impossible to anticipate such things. As recently [sic] as 25 years ago, it was completely unclear that the internet would become directly relevant to most peoples' lives, and the _manner_ and scope of its relevance nowadays would have been unimaginable at the time. Cell phone batteries were terrible, too, and memory was much less dense. Bandwidth was trivial. 56k phone modems!?! Given the last 25+ years, I hesitate to try to predict anything.

Comment: Do I, as an author submitting papers to the arXiv, want the successor of the arXiv to still have the same permissions?

Comment: @JessicaB Who decides which website is "the successor of the Arxiv"? Can I self-appoint myself as one? If so, then that license gives *everyone* a perpetual right to distribute the articles...

Comment: Wouldn't Law.SE be a better fit for this question?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is more to the question ***How future proof is the arXiv?***.

How future proof is *anything* in this day and age?

The license itself is built on the idea that the system will continue roughly as it currently does, but substantial unforeseen changes both technological and of society (doesn't have to be a war) can easily derail it, as you have outlined in the various scenarios.

However, I don't think there is any reason to worry (your scenarios are too pessimistic), since the arXiv serves a very good purpose to all involved parties:

- authors can quickly disseminate their results to all interested,
- the scientific community (in fact the world community) get open access to (preprint versions) of many published articles (most in certain fields), and
- the journals get a free preprint publication service which boosts their visibility and hence impact (since citations will be to the journal version, not the arXiv version - I know of no journal that disallows publication at arXiv). If a journal reverts this policy (in order to earn on copyrights), most authors of good articles will turn away from it.

Because of these points, funding at Cornell should be possible into foreseeable future.

Comment: This assumes that the publishers think in terms of preserving their impact factor, rather than in terms of copyright trolling. Something that might change if publishers start going bankrupt or getting bought up by hedge funds... And this is one of the more realistic scenarios: Pretty much everyone agrees the paid publishing model is not long for this world, at least in mathematics. Once the cash flow slows down, expect a fire sale...

Comment: @darijgrinberg Your scenario is not a danger, at least not in the long run. If a journal starts to copyright troll and disallow arXiv publication, authors (at least of the good papers worth reading) will stop publishing there. The journal cannot prevent arXiv access to articles published in the past.

Comment: Could the downvoters please explain how this answer can be improved and/or what is wrong with it?

Comment: You didn't actually answer the question that was asked.  The question was "how resilient would this be in the face of catastrophic events", and your answer was "Oh you don't need to worry about catastrophic events.  They're super-unlikely."  That's... not an answer.